# How to alert the user if he clicks on a div rel?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code of a wikieditor!

[image: This is the inspect]

`div rel="wikiEditor-ui-view-preview" class="current">`

The class changes to 'current' when the user clicks on Preview. How can I alert the user, if he clicks on Preview?

Comment: check for `.hasClass('current')`

Comment: you can bind a click event to your 'Preview' element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mocks the behaviour itself. For example, this will toggle the class of the parent to add `current` class. Just to prove that this check on it's class works

```
$("a").on('click', function() { 
    if ($(this).text() === "Preview") {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("current");
        checkCurrent();
    }
});

function checkCurrent() {
    if ($('div[rel="wikiEditor-ui-view-preview"]').hasClass("current")) {
        alert("hasClass");
    }
}
```

This will evaluate if the element has that specific class when clicked, if it does then the alert will fire

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjuuf9gh/1/) like what you want.

*(The link was updated to be more similar to your question)*

Comment: Glad to help :) please remember to accept & upvote the answer to help people in the future as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975188/how-to-insert-html-inside-a-div-rel Can you help in answering this question too?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply activate a function on a `rel` tag like this:

```js
$('div[rel="wikiEditor-ui-view-preview"]').on('click', function(){ 
  alert('hi');
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div rel="wikiEditor-ui-view-preview">
  test working
</div>
```

And you can combine that with a class like this:

```js
$('div[rel="wikiEditor-ui-view-preview"].active').on('click', function(){ 
  alert('hi');
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div rel="wikiEditor-ui-view-preview" class="active">
  test working because active class
</div>

<div rel="wikiEditor-ui-view-preview" class="anotherclass">
  test not working because not active
</div>
```

Comment: That does not work. I guess I have to use the class too. The class gets changed to 'current' when clicked!

Comment: @SrijanAgarwal The reason it would not be working, is because your question is not clear enough. Please elaborate on what you want the result to be.

Comment: So. This is the thing. 

I need to alert the user when he clicks the preview button. The class changes to 'current' when someone clicks on the preview!